# SELECT JOIN +Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM Employee AS A
LEFT JOIN  EmployeeHistory AS B ON +B.EmployeeId = CASE 
WHEN DeptId=1 THEN SUBSTRING(FunctionRef,2,3)
WHEN DeptId=2 THEN SUBSTRING(FunctionRef,2,2) END
```

I want to understand the `+` before the `+B.EmployeeId`, since SQL Server isn't throwing an error

Comment: *"since SQL Server isn't throwing an error"* are you sure about that? I get "Incorrect syntax near ON." [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a8c0afc0e50c4edf0228dc058f2524aa)

Comment: I don't think SQL Server supports this syntax.

Comment: If the *first* `ON` is meant to be a `JOIN`, it *does* work: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=973ac528a3d5e0dc39a368b1b6fba717). But all the `+` is doing is being a leading plus or concatenation operator. `SELECT +1, + '';` is perfectly valid (though odd) syntax. The `+` is basically doing nothing.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I just copy pasted the code as it is @Larnu

Comment: Then it won't run, @MartinJames ; not in SQL Server. As I showed. The first `ON` isn't valid.

Comment: That's not a valid query in SQL Server.

Comment: I can't imagine this exact syntax is valid in any rdbms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL you have posted is *not* valid T-SQL. This is because after you define the alias for `Employee` as `A` you have an `ON` ("A" is for Employee? What A? A is for Apple, *E* is for Employee. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)). The first table in a `FROM` can't be followed by an `ON`, `ON` is for tables that you are joining to.

If the *first* `ON` is meant to be a `JOIN`, it *does* work: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=973ac528a3d5e0dc39a368b1b6fba717). But all the `+` is doing is being a leading plus or concatenation operator (which depends on the data type of `EmployeeID`). `SELECT +1, + '';` is perfectly valid (though odd) syntax. The `+` is basically doing nothing.

*Disclaimer: The opening paragraph is based on the [original SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67506068/1) the OP posted, which they stated they had [copy and pasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506068/select-join-column/67506245?noredirect=1#comment119318709_67506068) from a working environment.*

Comment: That's really strange.  I'm surprised that this parses, if the + doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: It's not really. `SELECT -1, - DecimalColumn` is perfectly valid, @Andrew , so why would you expect `SELECT +1, + DecimalColumn` not to be? Yes, the `+` doesn't change the value, but it's an identical principle.

Comment: I guess I would have expected the + and - operators to require two arguments.

Comment: @Larnu can the + make inconsistent ouput for the join result ?

Comment: No, @MartinJames . `+ {someint}` or `+ {SomeString}` = `{someint]` and `{SomeString}` respectively. That doesn't mean tht e`+` should be there though.

Comment: @Larnu in which case it can cause a problem? a database migration fro example ?

Comment: In T-SQL, no. But again, that doesn't mean it should be there @MartinJames . It confused you, so it might confuse others in the future. Remove it, save the confusion.

Comment: IME a unary `+` is used to force *non*-sargeability, why you would want that is a different question...

Comment: Are you sure about that, @Charlieface ? 2 times seeks (not scans): [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=96e05b557b7b8fcd079d50af16e8cb7c)

Comment: I'll rephrase that: IME *some people* use it as such, clearly it doesn't work. Maybe it worked on SQL2000, or maybe it works on MySQL, dunno

Answer (score 2):

The `+` is a unary plus sign.  It is analogous to then unary minus (`-`) but it doesn't do anything.  If the second argument is a string, then it is a unary string concatenator, once again doing nothing.

I'm not sure what the purpose is.

You can check this out to get an idea:

```
select ++++1, + '', +'abc'
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot to include the second line `JOIN table2 as B`. If you included that line the query could become valid.

The `+B.EmployeeId` expression can mean `0+B.EmployeeId` and thus the plus sign would not have any effect.